# How to 'echo "" > x' on multiple files

Tags: bash, scripting

What is the best way how to empty a bunch of files in bash? As far I've been doing this

```
echo "" > development.log
echo "" > production.log
```

I don't really want to delete those files, so `rm` is not possible. I've tried many things like

```
echo "" > *.log
```

but nothing worked.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You don't need the echo. Just

```
>filename
```

will empty the file. To edit rassie...

```
for FILE in *.log
do
   >"${FILE}"
done
```

The quotes and brackets are preferred, as they will correctly handle files with spaces or special characters in them.

Comment: The one in the loop creates a file called {FILE}. The first quotation mark needs to go before the dollar sign instead of after.

Comment: Gak! Typo fixed.

Answer (score 3):

Just for fun, another variation combining Eric Dennis' `find` with everybody else's redirection:

```
find . -name "*.log" -exec sh -c ">{}" \;
```

Answer (score 1):

```
for i in *.log; do > $i; done
```

Note that if you really want the files to be emptied you have to use **no echo at all**, see above, or pass echo the -n flag (**echo -n**)

Answer (score 1):

```
for i in *.log; do cp /dev/null $i; done
```

Or, if you want to recurse:

```
find . -name "*.log" -exec cp /dev/null {} \;
```

Comment: you miss a ". ( 15 chars here :) )

Comment: after       log

Answer (score 0):

A loop could do:

```
for i in *.log; do echo "" > $i; done
```

Comment: We should be using echo with the -n flag to prevent putting a useless \n at the top of the file.

Answer (score 0):

**Solution**:

`echo -n | tee *.log`

**Explanation**:

`echo -n` echoes an empty string to stdout; while `tee *.log` writes stdout to mutiple files with widecard like you wished.

Answer (score -1):

This will also work.

```
find *.txt | awk '{print " " > $1}'
```